# Unable to install Git-core+svn by MacPorts

Tags: svn, git, macports

I am trying to install git-svn on mac os x 10.5 using the following command,

```
sudo port install git-core +svn
```

It installation is successful but i can find the git-svn command anywhere,

```
~/ $ sudo port installed git-*
The following ports are currently installed:
  git-core @1.6.5.2_0+doc+svn (active)
```

Installed shows it installed with correct options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `+svn` variant *is* installed. `git-svn` will be at `/opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn`, but you should call it from the command line as `git svn` -- `git` itself will know where to find its associated binaries.

`git` is installed at `/opt/local/bin`. Make sure `/opt/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for a git-svn binary.